# Query an XML using LINQ and excluding where an Attribute value is equal to that of an Element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list, nested

I have a LINQ query against an XML, that gives me a list of nested lists, each sublist being a list of an elements("row") attributes.

```
var items = loadbodies.Descendants("row").Select(a => a.Attributes().Select(b => b.Value).ToList()).ToList();
```

This works as intended but, what I actually need to is query this against another list of values so as not to have sublists added where one of the elements attributes("messageID") is on the second list. I can do this for one value but need to check it against the entire second list.

The query to exclude a single sublist by a single hardcoded value from the second list is below.

```
var items = loadbodies.Descendants("row").Where(c => (string)c.Attribute("messageID") != "avaluefromthesecondlist").Select(a => a.Attributes().Select(b => b.Value).ToList()).ToList();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Contains`. Note that splitting lines helps readability considerably:

```
var ids = ...; // Some sequence of ids, e.g. a List<string> or HashSet<string>
var items = loadbodies
      .Descendants("row")
      .Where(row => ids.Contains((string) row.Attribute("messageId")))
      .Select(a => a.Attributes()
                    .Select(b => b.Value)
                    .ToList())
      .ToList();
```

Note that you could use a `Join` call too... but so long as you've got relatively few IDs, this should be fine.

Comment: Apologies for the single line, it did not occur to me that it may affect others readability. I am getting a "bool does not contain a definition for 'Select'" error?

Comment: @Syrsyrian: I'd missed one closing bracket - try again now.

Comment: Perfect. Out of curiosity, is there something that would be similar to "Contains" but inverse, such as "DoesNotContain"?

Comment: @Syrsyrian: Sure: `!ids.Contains(...)`

Comment: Awesome, I had just tried ".Except" but that obviously didn't work as intended. Thanks very much for your help.